# XML to JSON conversion accessing member in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I have an XML string like

```
<Segment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Air">
   <carrier />
   ...
</Segment>
```

I use JSON.NET to convert that to JSON and the end result has the following members

```
@xmlns:xsi: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
@xsi:type: "Air"
carrier
```

At client end, how do I access the type "Air"? `Segment.@xsi:type` obviously is illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you use Json.Net at client end.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xstr);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xDoc);


JObject jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);
string air = jObj["Segment"]["@xsi:type"].ToString();
//or
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonText);
string air = jObj.Segment["@xsi:type"];
```